# Power 10**10 gives the wrong output. what could be the reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A trainee of mine made this short python script for a problem from Project Euler.

We are using `Python 3.9.4`

Problem: The series, 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + 10<sup>10</sup> = 10405071317. Find the last ten digits of the series, 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + 1000<sup>1000</sup>.

It isn't the best solution but in theory it should work for small values(I know it wont work for bigger values to inefficient and even double is too small.

Here is her Code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1,11)
a=[]

for y in x:
     z = y**y
     a.append(z)

b=sum(a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489, 1410065408]
```

The script isn't finished yet obviously but you can see that every power 1<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, 3<sup>3</sup> are correct up to 10<sup>10</sup> which does not return the correct value.

Do you see any reason for this problem it seem quite odd to me? I could not figure it out.

Yes I know this isn't the best solution and in the end the actually solution will be different but it would still be nice to solve this mystery.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably on some kind of 32-bit systems where numpy defaults to 32-bit integers. This caused the result to be "truncated" to 32 bits. You can verify the result with the following expression:

```
(10 ** 10) % (2 ** 32)
```

Use Python built-in `int` and `range` unless you need the fancy stuff numpy provides. It's an arbitrary-precision integer implementation and should work for all kinds of integer calculation workload.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check that right away. The output from your expression is: "1410065408". I checked the interpreter and it clearly says 64 bit. But when we changed "x = np.arange(1,11)" to "x = np.arange(1,11, dtype = np.int64) it worked as you forecasted. Thx a lot!

Comment: @PatrickGooderMusicHelbingk Note that `2**64` (64 bit integer) is on the order of `10**19`. `1000**1000` will be `10**3000`. You might be better off using regular Python instead of trying to find a type that will be able to handle such large numbers because Python will handle the numbers for you.

Comment: For us it defaulted to 32 bit on our systems at "work" but she tried it at home yesterday evening and it also defaulted to 64 bit(It worked) so maybe there was recent update in numpy?

Comment: @PatrickGooderMusicHelbingk It's impossible that "a recent update" caused the change, but more likely platform differences. For example between OSs or architectures.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is to not use `numpy` unnecessarily. The built-in `range` works very well:

```
import math

a=[]

for y in range(1, 11):
     z = y**y
     a.append(z)

b=sum(a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

In your case, `numpy` was using 32 bit integers, which overflowed when they reached their maximum value.

Comment: Thanks a lot it indeed was an overflow. I know the built in range works just fine that's how I would have done it but she does python since like 2 days and I told her that the built in range is better in this case but it still was a good idea to know why it failed imo. Embarrassed i did not see it.

Comment: @PatrickGooderMusicHelbingk As a developer who is most experienced in Python, when I move to languages like Rust where I have to declare types I sometimes experience overflows because I don't realize how often I work with large numbers. It is so easy to take for granted the fact that Python will handle the size of your number in the background.

Comment: Next optimization would be to throw out the unneeded creation of the list and to use a generator expression instead: `sum(y**y for y in range(1, 11))`